# How to create multiple classes dependent on each other in python

Tags: python

I was trying to create an interpreted language and was creating baseline classes for them and wanted to know how I would go about making that module work as I get errors of bad references to names that are not defined yet because they were written after each other. This is hard to explain but I can show you an example:

```
class baseClass:
   def __init__(self):pass
class number(baseClass):
   def __init__(self,num:literal|decimal):pass
class decimal(baseClass):
   def __init__(self,num:literal|number):pass
class literal(baseClass):
   def __init__(self,val:number,decimal):pass
```

In this case there are multiple classes that rely on each other simultaneously and will raise errors when you try and define this module because one isn't defined at the time it's being referenced. And for the record the model I showed you isn't the exact thing it is closer to a stub. I want to create the implementation and have the interpreter to call all of these but I cannot progress until I get the reference issue fixed.

Comment: It's not necessary to annotate types at all in Python.

Comment: I want to do it as part of documentation